# JQuery Auto complete set text to text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json string something like this below:

```
[
    {
        "CustomerCountryId": "1",
        "CountryName": "Australia"
    },

    {
        "CustomerCountryId": "1",
        "CountryName": "Austria"
    },

    {
        "CustomerCountryId": "1",
        "CountryName": "Belgium"
    }
]
```

I want to use `JQuery` auto complete to set `CountryName` to text box and `"CustomerCountryId"`it is not showing data in autocomplete box when I type country name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method: convert your data to an `Array` of `label`, `value` and `id` properties and next get the `id` property in the select function:

**HTML Code:**

```
<input id="search" />
<input type="text" id="CustomerCountryId" />
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var data = [
  {
    "CustomerCountryId": "3",
    "CountryName": "Australia"
  },

  {
    "CustomerCountryId": "2",
    "CountryName": "Austria"
  },

  {
    "CustomerCountryId": "1",
    "CountryName": "Belgium"
  }
];

$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: data.reduce(function(array, item){
    array = array || [];
    array.push({label: item.CountryName, value: item.CountryName, id: item.CustomerCountryId});
    return array;
  }, []),
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#CustomerCountryId").val(ui.item.id);
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/o5o7zdo5/)

Comment: Thank you @elchininet :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) If this answer is useful to you, mark it as the correct answer.